# How is the expression for Bias-Variance obtained?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, variance

> In
>   [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=503&v=7jk5HuuHLNE)
>   video lecture they say:
>
> If $Y=f(X) + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is the error for input $X$, then
>   expectation value $E[\epsilon]=0$ and $\text{Var}[\epsilon]=\sigma^2$.
>
> Then it is said that
>
> $\text{EPE}(x_0)=E[(Y-f(x_0))^2|X=x_0]$        ----------- $(1)$
>
> $\implies \text{EPE}(x_0)=E[(E[\hat{f}(x_0)]-\hat{f}(x_0))^2|X=x_0] +
>  E[\hat{f}(x_0)-E[Y]]^2+\sigma^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{k}$   -------- $(2)$
>
> The first term on the right hand side is called the variance and the
>   second term is called the bias.
>
> $\implies \text{EPE}(x_0) = \frac{\sigma^2}{k} +
>  [f(x_0)-E[\frac{1}{k}\sum_{l=1}^{k}f(x_{(l)})]]^2 + \sigma^2$
>   ---------- $(3)$

Questions:

- How do we get to step $(2)$ from step $(1)$? What does $\hat{f}$ mean?
- Why is the variance term $\sigma^2/k$ ($k$ I think is the number of sample data points)?
- Why does the bias term equal $[f(x_0)-E[\frac{1}{k}\sum_{l=1}^{k}f(x_{(l)})]]^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

In step 1 we have that $\textrm{ESE} = \textrm{E}[(Y-f(x_0))^2]$. By adding and subtracting $E[\hat{f}(x_0)]$ we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textrm{ESE} & = \textrm{E}[(Y-f(x_0))^2]\\
 & = \textrm{E}[(Y-\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)] + \textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]- f(x_0))^2]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Expanding this equation gives us the outer and inner terms squared, and the cross terms:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textrm{ESE} & = \textrm{E}[(Y-f(x_0))^2]\\
 & = \textrm{E}[(Y-\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)])^2] + \textrm{E}[(\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]- f(x_0))^2] + 2\textrm{E}[(Y-\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)])(\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]- f(x_0))]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Note that all of the values in the second expectation are constants, so we can get rid of the outer expectation and obtain:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\textrm{ESE} & = \textrm{E}[(Y-\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)])^2] + (\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]- f(x_0))^2 + 2\textrm{E}[(Y-\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)])(\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]- f(x_0))]
\end{split}
\end{equation}

So we can see that the first term is the variance, the escond term is the bias of the estimate $\hat{f}(x_0)$ squared, and the right term is left to deal with.

If we can show that the right term is $0$, then we are done.

Expanding the righthand term gives us:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
2\textrm{E}[(Y-\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)])(\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]- f(x_0))] & = 2\textrm{E}[Y\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]-\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]^2 -\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]f(x_0) + Yf(x_0)]\\
&=  2(\textrm{E}[Y]\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]-\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]^2 -\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)]f(x_0) + \textrm{E}[Y]f(x_0))
\end{split}
\end{equation}

If $\textrm{E}[\hat{f}(x_0)] = f(x_0)$ then these terms cancel and we get just the bias and variance.